# How to use @Cacheable with redis using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am trying to implement hashmap using redis but I would like to control the key myself, so I have implemented following service class.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class RedisService {
    Map<Long, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "studentCache")
    public Map<Long, Student> getStudentCache(){
        return studentMap;
    }
}
```

my pojo class is

```
@Data
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2722504679276149008L;
    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;
    private int grade;

}
```

and the data loader

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    RedisService redisService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
      log.info("================ loading data now ========================");
        Student student = getStudent();
        redisService.getStudentCache().put(student.getId(), student);
        System.out.println("student is "+redisService.getStudentCache().get(student.getId()));
        log.info("================= program ends ==============");
    }

    private Student getStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong());
        student.setName("first last");
        student.setGender(Student.Gender.MALE);
        student.setGrade(85);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have successfull connection with redis but it does not seems to be putting anything in the cache. When I run the program I got following message as outcome.

```
2020-09-10 15:26:37.605  INFO 28540 --- [           main] c.w.s.components.DataLoader              : ================ loading data now ========================
student is null
2020-09-10 15:26:38.295  INFO 28540 --- [           main] c.w.s.components.DataLoader              : ================= program ends ==============
```

So I am not sure why student is returning **NULL** any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cache is being initialized when you access cached data for the first time (to be specific - data for the specific caching key - in this case constant). In your case it's happenning at the end of first call to `redisService.getStudentCache()`. At that time `studentMap` is an empty map, hence empty map is being cached. The fact that moment later you add there some entry (via `.put(student.getId(), student);`) doesn't matter because caching system is using its own copy of cached map, hence null on getting value from this map.

Comment: Thank you @Adam - so how do I put some data in that ?

Comment: Basically method annotated as `@Cacheable` should obtain/calculate/fetch data inside it's body (in your case inside `RedisService.getStudentCache()`). Usually it's some heavy operation. If cached data require change, cache entry associated with it should be invalidated i.e. via `@CacheEvict` / `@CachePut` or directly via `CacheManager & Cache bean`. In general cache entries should be invalidated significantly less frequent than accessing cached data, otherwise there is no point in having cache. In such maybe maybe cache is not what you need.